# (raspberry pi) instead of pip install all the function (like pandas and json), but we can still use them in script import

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi4, pi, mpi4py

system: raspberry pi 4 model B, 32bit, linux run python

Is a dumb question, I was planning to `read data from MongoDB to excel` and also `read excel toMongoDB`. Overall the .py scrip/code is fine and working. (the code is below)

> I do know if in the code I do *"import pandas as pd"* then raspberry pi cmd
> need to pip install it

- my main quesion:

**but we also acknowledge that raspberrypi's memory not as bigger as other laptop, is there other way instead of pip install all the stuff, we can still use them?**
Becides, I only pip install pandas by raspberrypi took about 15 min, and laptop is like 30sec, and factory might have more than hundred of raspberrypis for recording such as temperature, product data etc on production line.

**There should be an efficient way to implement (use pandas and other pymongo without manually pip install on raspberrypi)**

- the memory left:

> joy@raspberrypi:/ $ free
> 3834332/total  , 223876/used , 2844436/free

- the  fine code.py script MongoDB to excel:

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo
from json2excel import Json2Excel
import json
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from bson import json_util

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
# Database Name
db = client["(practice_10_14)-0002"]
# Collection Name
col = db["(practice_10_24)read_MongoDB_to_Excel"]
#  Find All: It works like Select * query  of SQL. 
x = col.find()
list_01 = []
for data in x:
    list_01.append(data)
    print(data)


print("= = = = = ")
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=[0])
 
# select two columns
for y in df:
    print(y)

print("= = = = = ")
print(type(list_01))


print(list_01)
df = pd.DataFrame(list_01)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test10.24.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='welcome', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: If you need to configure *hundreds* of Raspberry Pi's to perform the same task, instead of manually setting up each of them from scratch, it may be better to create a customized image containing your application, and use the image for all devices. Whether doing it this way would save time depends on the scale of your deployment, though.

Comment: thanks @kotatsuyaki, that seems one of  the nice solution, then I might need to create a customized image

Comment: For this relatively simple example you could avoid Pandas and install and write with xlsxwriter directly, which is a much smaller dependency. It would depend if you also need Pandas elsewhere in your application.